# Are there any jvms designed for programs that need to start quickly(like scripts)

Tags: scripting, jvm, startup

If I want to write a java(or other jvm language script)

Maybe by doing something like caching jit results?
What about gcj compiled binaries?
(P.S. if you could explain waht techniques it uses to decrease startup time)

Answer (score 1):

See https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21255195 for such example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Nailgun: Insanely Fast Java](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/).  It runs a JVM server in the background and provides a thin client written in C to pass command line arguments and environment variables to the server process.

It means that all your scripts run in the same JVM server process, but avoids the startup overhead.